# Let $S=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=0, 0<y<1\}$. Is $S$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=0, 0<y<1\}$. Is $S$ closed?

I tried by claiming “$S$ is closed”. Then it’s complement, let’s say $W$, would be open. And the set $W$ would be $W=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}, (-\infty, 0]\cup[1,\infty)\}$.

But I don’t know if I'm doing it corect, and if I am, I'm not sure if I would be done by picking a point $p$ in $W$ and showing that there exists and $\epsilon$ greater than $0$ such that $D(p, \epsilon)$ is a subset of $W$ (which completes the proof, again, if I'm not wrong).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: For example, use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, i edited it thanks :)

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: NO.....................................

Comment: I tried by claiming “S is closed”. Then it’s complement, let’s say W, would be open. And the set W would be $W=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}, (-\infty, 0]\bigcup[1,\infty)\}$. But i don’t know if i’m doing it corect, and if i am, i’m not sure if i would be done by picking a point p in W and showing that there exists and epsilon greater than 0 such that D(p, epsilon) is a subset of W (which completes the proof, again, if i’m not wrong).

Comment: @Nana **Edit your question** to include the attempt you described in your comment and I'll nominate the question for reopening.  Then ask yourself whether $(0, 0)$ is in the interior of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus S$.  Ask yourself the same question about $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @RobertShore I have edited the question. Clearly not, and the points you’ve given as an example are the bounaries of the S. So is open, if i’m not wrong.

Comment: It's also possible for a set to be neither closed nor open.  But all you're asked to determine is whether it's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Claim: S is closed.*

Since we claimed that $S$ is closed, then by the below definition, complement of $S$, that is $\mathbb{R^2}\,\backslash \,S$, is open.

> A set $S$ in a metrix space $(M,d)$ is said to be closed if it's complement, that is, $M\,\backslash\, S=S^c$ is open.

So if we can prove that the complement of $S$ is indeed open, then we'll be done.
And to prove that $S^c$ is open, we are going to use the definition as follows:

> A set S is said to be open if $\,\forall x\in S$,$\;\exists \varepsilon > 0$ such that $D(x,\varepsilon)\subset\,S$.

First, let me write the correct complement of $S$:

$\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash S = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\;|\;y\le 0\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\;|\;1\le y\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\;|\;x\neq0\}$

Now, let's choose a point in $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash S$. Let it be $a=(1,0)\in\mathbb{R^2}\,\backslash\,S$. Then if we use the second definition i have given previously, we should get:

$$for\;any\;\, \varepsilon > 0,\;D(a,\varepsilon)\subset\mathbb{R^2}\backslash\,S$$

But it is not the case since there are some points $(x,y)\in D(a,\varepsilon)$ where $0<y<1$, but $(x,y)\notin \mathbb{R^2}\,\backslash\,S$.

Therefore $\mathbb{R^2}\,\backslash\,S$ is not open, which implies that $S$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to see the set is not closed is to make use of the fact that a set is closed if and only if the limit of every converging sequence of elements from the set is in the set. We can clearly see it does not hold in this case since $\{(0,\frac{1}{2n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in S$ whoever $\{(0,\frac{1}{2n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow (0,0) \notin S$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your definition of "open" and closed" is here.

> **Definition of "open in $\mathbb R^2\ $"**
>
> For $A\subset \mathbb R^2,$
>
> $A$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ $\underset{\mathrm{def}}\iff \forall a\in A, \exists\delta>0$ s.t. $B(a,\delta)\subset A.$

> **Definition of "closed in $\mathbb R^2\ $"**
>
> For $B\subset \mathbb R^2,$
>
> $B$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$ $\underset{\mathrm{def}}\iff \mathbb R^2\setminus B$ is open in $\mathbb R^2.$

And you are trying to determine $\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ or not.

Then, for the simplicity, rewrite $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x=0, 0<y<1\}$ as $$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x=0, 0<y\}\cap\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x=0, y<1\}.$$
Then, you get
$$\mathbb R^2\setminus S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\neq 0, 0\geqq y\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\neq 0, y\geqq 1\}.$$

Then, in order to determine this is open or not, you have to determine whether
$$\forall a\in \mathbb R^2\setminus S, \exists\delta>0 \ \mathrm{s.t.} \ B(a,\delta)\subset\mathbb R^2\setminus S$$ holds or not.

If this holds, then $\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ and thus $S$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$. If this doesn't hold, then $\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2$ and thus $S$ is not closed in $\mathbb R^2$.

And, indeed, that doesn't hold. The reason is as below.

If you take $a=(0,0)$, you have $a\in\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ but for any $\delta>0$, we see $B(a,\delta)\not\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus S.$ (Do you see why $B(a,\delta)\not\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus S$ ?)

---

**Edit for showing $B(a,\delta)\not\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus S$.**

To show $B(a,\delta)\not\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus S$, you have to find $b$ such that $$b\in B(a,\delta) \quad \mathrm{but}\quad b\notin\mathbb R^2\setminus S,$$
i.e.,
$$b\in B(a,\delta) \quad \mathrm{but}\quad b\in S.$$

Drawing a picture helps us find such $b$. (Remember that $a=(0,0).$)

By drawing a picture, we can see that such $b$ must be in $B(a,\delta)$ from the condition that $b\in B(a,\delta)$, and must be on the line from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ (not containing $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$) from the condition that $b\in S.$

So, if you take $b:=\big(0,\min\{\frac{\delta}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}\big)$, you can see $b\in B(a,\delta)$ and $b\in S.$

$b\in B(a,\delta)$ follows from
$$\|b-a\|=\min\{\tfrac{\delta}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\}\leqq\tfrac{\delta}{2}<\delta,$$
and $b\in S$ follows from
$0<\min\{\frac{\delta}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}\leqq\frac{1}{2}<1.$

Comment: I guess I do. Since any disk about $(0,0)$ contains points $(x,y)$ where $x = 0$ and $0\lt y \lt 1$. But is $a=(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash S$?

Comment: $a=(0,0)\in\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ is true but it is doesn't matter in order to show $B(a,\delta)\not\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus S$. As you say, any disk around $(0,0)$ contains $(0,y)$ where $0<y<1$. You should clarify what you have to prove.  I added the explanation for showing $B(a,\delta)\not\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus S$.  @Nana

Comment: Sorry to inform you that i had to undo your answer as the "answer". I asked this question a day before i had a quiz, and in the quiz there was a pretty much similar question to this.  I used your way of solving to answer the question. But the definition of complement set was wrong, and I also picked a point similar to you did. But the assistant noted that this point was indeed not in the set according to my definition.